# Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am working on an existing .Net 6 application. I could see there are many of these exceptions in the logs.

> Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly.
> See MinRequestBodyDataRate.

When I googled it then found a similar issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1305885/why-do-we-get-this-error-reading-the-request-body), But in the accepted answer the user mentioned setting the value of `MinRequestBodyDataRate` as 1024, and in my opinion, it should be set to < 240 (240 is the default value) value. because as per the exception message and the description it is saying that it is receiving the request at a slower rate so ideally so, it means the requester is sending the lesser than the expected bytes per second, so I think I should set it to a lesser value.

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.minrequestbodydatarate?view=aspnetcore-6.0) doc as well, but didn't help much.

I am confused because, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64935332/6527049) answer, the user has set the value to 100.

Also, I didn't understand what is a grace period in this context.

**Note**: I cannot reproduce it in my local system, which I why I can't try and test this. It's happening only in production applications.

Comment: I also confused with that answer, From this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0), When the rate drops below the minimum, the connection is timed out. So it specify the value to 100.